# QGIS how to center the map while drawing a line

Tags: qgis, drawing, center

I have a line shapefile which represents a delivery route.
I am able to extent this route by drawing, using an OSM layer for snapping. (works great!)

Since I need a certain zoom level to see what I am doing, I run out of map soon.
Then I have to drag the map manually. And after that go back to drawing.
In the mean while I haven't saved my layer.

Is there a way of centering that map on my last vertex?
While drawing that is?
It wil be in memory somewhere.

QGIS is aware of the last vertex, as shown in my  image.

[image: last vertex]

Comment: While in drawing mode, click the mouse wheel and then drag the map. No need to switch tools.

Comment: technically it's "middle button" rather than the mouse wheel (though that is often where it is mapped on 2 button mice)

Comment: Thanks, it is so simple!